Can I calculate the X value of a specific AUC of a plot in R
I want to calculate the X-value corresponding to 95% of the area under the curve of the whole plot.
My data:
x <- seq(0,1, by=0.001)
y <- 1/x

plot(FP,LR, type="l",
     col = "red",
     ylim = c(0,300),
     xlim = c(0,0.15))

enter image description here
I want to find the X-value where there is a probability of 95% that the Y-value is higher. Since I do not have a normal distribution I can't use the quartile function.
I tried an asymmetric distribution but can't get the code to work with my plot.
So I calculated the AUC with:
auc(x,y, from = 0.001, to = 1)

It gave me the answer of auc= 6.984971
What I calculate is that an auc of 6.635722 is 95% of the total auc. If I can get the X-value corresponding to this auc It will give me my answer.
Is there a way to do this?
